# Accessing X-Server from within a Docker container on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, mono

I'm porting an old .NET Web API application to run on Heroku in a Docker container. I'm using a Mono image to do so.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mono:latest
EXPOSE 5000
ENV PORT 5000
ADD ./ /api
WORKDIR /api
RUN nuget restore -NonInteractive
RUN msbuild webapi.sln /p:Configuration=Release
CMD mono /api/MyProject/bin/Release/MyProject.exe port:$PORT
```

Pretty straightforward, use the latest Mono image, copy the source, restore the NuGet Packages, build the solution and run it. The $PORT environment variable get set by Heroku or defaults to 5000 for my local development environment.

It all works great, except for one specific API controller which generates a PDF report. The report is generated by PdfSharp which has a dependency on the System.Drawing assembly for the necessary rendering. However this means having a dependency on the display.

When I call that controller to generate a report I get the following error.

```
Could not open display (X-Server required. Check your DISPLAY environment variable).
```

I require access to an X-Server in order to do the necessary rendering. I have tried numerous things, but am always stuck at this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by installing Xvfb (virtual framebuffer), a display server which implements the X11 display server protocol. You can take a look at the updated Dockerfile below.

**Remark**: Apart from the display server there were more problems with getting PDFSharp to run on Mono. I also had to update the apt sources and install the Microsoft Core Fonts, because the reports I generate use them. 
I also had to use a modified version of PDFSharp which knows how to locate the fonts. Luckily this was already done for me:

https://github.com/daniellor/PDFsharp

The relevant code is here:

https://github.com/daniellor/PDFsharp/blob/master/src/PdfSharp/Fonts/FontLocalizator.cs

A bit hacky and you might need to modify it to suit your setup, but it does the job. Just create a MonoRelease build and reference this assembly and you are good to go.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mono:latest

# Update the sources.list for apt-get so it knows where to download the Microsoft Core fonts.
RUN echo "deb http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com wheezy contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com wheezy-updates contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Install Xvfb and the Microsoft core fonts
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb ttf-mscorefonts-installer

# Configure Xvfb as a daemon.
ADD xvfb.init /etc/init.d/xvfb
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/xvfb
RUN update-rc.d xvfb defaults

EXPOSE 5000
ENV PORT 5000
ADD ./ /api
WORKDIR /api
RUN nuget restore -NonInteractive
RUN msbuild webapi.sln /p:Configuration=Release

# Start Xvfb and the Web Api
CMD (service xvfb start; export DISPLAY=:10; mono /api/MyProject/bin/Release/MyProject.exe port:$PORT)
```

**xvfb.init**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# /etc/rc.d/init.d/xvfbd
#
# chkconfig: 345 95 28
# description: Starts/Stops X Virtual Framebuffer server
# processname: Xvfb
#

[ "${NETWORKING}" = "no" ] && exit 0

PROG="/usr/bin/Xvfb"
PROG_OPTIONS=":10 -ac"
PROG_OUTPUT="/tmp/Xvfb.out"

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting : X Virtual Frame Buffer "
        $PROG $PROG_OPTIONS>>$PROG_OUTPUT 2>&1 &
        disown -ar
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down : X Virtual Frame Buffer"
        killproc $PROG
        RETVAL=$?
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && /bin/rm -f /var/lock/subsys/Xvfb/var/run/Xvfb.pid
        echo
        ;;
    restart|reload)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
    status)
        status Xvfb
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
    *)
     echo $"Usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|reload|status)"
     exit 1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```